# MySQL query to return results in specific order without order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to make a mysql query returning values without default order.for example am using the below query

```
select id_product,name from sample where id_product in ('675','123','745','954').
```

but it giving the output rows order by id_product. 
OUTPUT:

```
id_product,Name
123        ,abc
675        ,xzy
745        ,bsh
954        ,dsh
```

I want the result should come like this, without default order.

```
 id_product,Name
 675        ,xzy
123        ,abc    
745        ,bsh
954        ,dsh
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean order them randomly?

Comment: you want them completely random? Can you not just get your results and jumble them?

Comment: Do you want them ordered in the same way as your `IN` clause?  You need to clarify.

Comment: yes @ TOM..is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding a `Sort` column in the database to force a custom order. Anyway, you can use a little trick using the [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT id_product, name
FROM sample
WHERE id_product IN (675,123,745,954)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id_product, '675,123,745,954')
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b191/5)

Answer (score 5):

There's always an order. If you do not specify any particular using `ORDER BY` then rows can be returned in the order they are stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you want random order : "order by rand()";

Comment: but don't forget that, "order by rand()" works slow on big datasets.

Comment: OP does not want the results returned in random order, look at the output closely.

Comment: yes salman.. I dont want to sort by random. I want to sort it as like the id's I passed in IN query..

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a random order, you could do this:

```
SELECT id_product,name FROM sample WHERE id_product IN ('675','123','745','954') 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have defined an ordered `index` on `id_product` column of the table. Please check it.

Otherwise, the select will result in the default order of rows insertion.

**Refer to**: [***Create Index - MySQL***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)